# Is it correct to say 'We will do it when we got a decision'?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Someone will make a decision, then we receive it, and do something according to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tenses are mixed here, making the sentence incomprehensible. Your sentence would be grammatically correct if you said, "We will do it we when we ***get*** a decision."

Answer (score 0):

The verb tense of the sentence is inconsistent. The sentence would be correct if changed to either "We **did** it when we got a decision.", "We will do it when we **get** a decision." or "We will do it **once** we **have gotten** a decision.". However, as the majority of my English teachers drilled into me, "don't use got/get/things/stuff". Even though these are grammatically correct, the teachers dislike them due to their non-descriptiveness. They would have you rewrite the sentence to something like "We will do it **once** we **have come to** a decision.".

Comment: In this sentence "We will do it once we have come to a decision." is someone else come to decision or we are?